# configurable location of .rpmmacros file

Tags: macros, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How to pass the location of `.rpmmacros file` in `rpmbuild` command ?

by default it try to look for it in home dir.

I tried `-rcfiles /location/to/.rpmmacros` but it gave me

```
error: missing ':' (found 0x2f) at /usr/local/.rpmmacros:1
```

content of .rpmmacros

```
%_topdir       /usr/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Am not an expert myself, but shouldn't it be --rcfil=location_to_rpmrc

And the rpmrc file should contain the path to rpmmacros in the format

macrofiles::full_path_to_rpmmacros_file

Comment: I suggest you add some code blocks to make your comment easier to read. Also, using punctuation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

With RPM version 4.12.0.1, you can specify the rpmmacro file as follows:
`rpmbuild --macros=<YOUR_LOCAL_MACRO> <YOUR_LOCAL_SPEC_FILE>`

after replacing  and  with corresponding path to your files.